# Java 8 Stream Map Collector Error - role cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security, jpa-2.1

I am new to spring security. I was trying to creating my first project using spring  boot and spring security with the help of this [tutorial](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-hibernate-mysql-tutorial.html)

In **UserServiceImpl** file there is a function **mapRolesToAuthorities**, it takes **Collection < Role > roles** as a parameter.

Now the problem is, when I try to **stream** and **map** the **roles** like this

```
private Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority > 
mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection < Role > roles) 
    {
    return roles.stream().map(role - > new 
    SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRolename()))           
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

It shows error that

> role cannot be resolved to a variable

.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo with extra space in lambda operator:

```
role - >
```

should be

```
role ->
```